# Mobile Media Queries for retina

Tags: css, image, mobile, less, retina

I have a little problem with media query for retina images.

I have this block.less:

```
.page-header {
  background: @bg-dark url("../images/bg-back-mobile.jpg") no-repeat center top;

  @media @retina {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-back-mobile@2x.jpg");
    background-size: 700px auto;
  }
}

@media @tablet-width {
  .page-header {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-back-tablet@1x.jpg");

    @media @retina {
      background-image: url("../images/bg-back-tablet@2x.jpg");
      background-size: 1200px auto;
    }
  }
}

@media @desktop-width {
  .page-header {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-back-desktop.jpg");
  }
}
```

and vars.less:

```
@tablet-width: ~"(min-width: 700px)";
@desktop-width: ~"(min-width: 1200px)";
@retina: ~"(min-resolution: 144dpi), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)";
```

When I'm testing this background-image on mobile device (width: 320px, DPR: 2.0), there is downoading `url("../images/bg-back-tablet@2x.jpg")` but not `url("../images/bg-back-mobile@2x.jpg")`.

When I delete this part

```
@media @retina {
          background-image: url("../images/bg-back-tablet@2x.jpg");
          background-size: 1200px auto;
        }
```

it's working right.

What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there a reason you don't want to just always use the full-res image?

Comment: no, I can't. it's the technical task.